# Replacement crankset for Shimano SG B 52/39?

Tags: chainring, crankset, replacement

I have a very basic Specialized Allez (XL frame) street bike (pictured in my avatar) with a cheap SG B52/39 chainring needing replacement (warped and wearing out after two years of daily use).

But here in Costa Rica the LBS can't seem to find a replacement chainring the same size as I have. They only offer me compact cranksets which I don't accept since I already max out on the flats to the the 52T/12T top gear combination. Therefore I need to figure out what chainring/crankset to order myself the US online.

Unfortunately, I don't know what to order that will fit (something one tends to rely on the LBS to get right) my bike as it is.

So I'm coming to y'all. What do you recommend I get? Here's my details:

1. **Teeth**: I learned from [this article](http://blog.performancebike.com/2013/11/08/our-take-race-vs-compact-cranksets/) that there are racing, compact and even mid-compact chainrings. I think I prefer the mid-compact of 52/36T. If not possible, a racing of 53/39. Are both possible?
2. **Crankshaft**: Also, my current crankshaft is 170mm and I don't know if that's what I should get on the next chainring. I am 6' tall and have a 33-34" inseam.
3. **Quality**: My focus is durability; I ride every day. I don't want to pay a lot for something light since I'm not racing but I also don't want another cheap chainring that bends easily like the stock one did.

I'm hoping you can recommend an exact model chainring or crankset and maybe even where the best place to mail order it is (to a US address from which someone will bring it down to me).

Thanks in advance.

P.S. In case it matters, the stock 8-speed cassette in the back seems fine (Shimano CS HG50 12-25T). I also have a new Shimano Sora RD-3500 rear derailer doing well. The front derailer is the stock Shimano Sora FD-3400

Comment: Your bike sounds pretty standard to be honest. Your best bet is to look at the Shimano web site, I would be surprised if you can't find everything listed on there in the USA. Certainly 52/39 is a standard combination.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what standard means. What would help is to know specifically what I have now for a crankset (2200? 2300?) and what I should aim for (Sora? but Sora does not list a 52T crankset. Nor does Claris) 2300 may be what I need as it lists a 52T model?

Comment: By standard, I mean that your requirements can probably be satisfied by a number of parts. If the cranks don't exist in the Sora range, try looking up the ranges - Tiagra, 105, Ultegra, Dura Ace. The only thing you need to be aware of is that cranks are built for a certain speed (e.g. 10-speed) and the manufacturers recommend matching this speed with the number of gears on your cassette. The trouble with this question is that it sounds very much like you're looking for a product rec, and such questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Oh! yes I am but thanks for the gentle correction on that. I guess I should delete my question? And thanks for the tips.

Comment: 3400 and 3500 are both 9-speed systems, I believe. You might be able to find a Tiagra part to suit (that'll probably be the FC-4500, from around 5 years ago) but you'll have trouble finding anything in any of the better groupsets, where they left 9-speed behind > 10 years ago I think. Also, 10-speed cranks will be a lot easier to find (I think the current Tiagra is 10-speed), just not a "perfect" fit.

Comment: If they left 9-speed behind, then what about 8-speed like my stock cassette? I'm getting the sense I should upgrade this bike to 10-speed parts.

Comment: yep....you're probably also getting the impression that you're being forced to upgrade by the bike manufacturers. And you are, it is a bit naughty. If you're running an 8-speed cassette, then 8-speed rings will be absolutely fine, if you can find them.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, naughty indeed. So this explains all the trouble I'm having and why I've seen glimpses of exact replacement parts only on eBay!

Comment: I doubt you're really maxing out a 52/12 on the flats, given that at a good cycling cadence (say, 80 rpm), you'd be doing around 28 mph.

Comment: Right, well I didnt say I max out the 52/12 on the flats, I said I max out TO that gear on the flats. IOW, I don't have good cycling cadence of 80 and like to cruise in that top gear at a lower cadence. I only max out that gear on declines and often wish I had a 53T/11T gear for that. =)

Comment: If you look on Shimano's (US) site, check out the [FC-2300](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/components1/road/2300.html) which is an 8-speed 52/39 crankset. The only reservation is that the 2300 group is quite some way down Shimano's product range....I'm not sure how good it is, basically

Comment: I discovered the stock one is this: http://www.amazon.com/SHIMANO-CRANKSET-SHI-FC-A050-170x52x39T/dp/B00DMI76PO (FC A050). So I think the FC-2300 is better. I'm trying to find one on Amazon...with Prime...no luck yet.

Comment: I found this one that should fit my bike http://www.amazon.com/Origin8-Pro-Pulsion-Road-Standard/dp/B003CO4RAK/ and I think this spec sheet for my current confirms it as it's 110mm spindle as well: http://www.birota.ru/manuals/shimano/allinone/1EY0A_EN.PDF

Comment: I'm going to order it ^ if no one sees a problem...

Comment: If the cranks are fine and only the large chainring needs replacement, something like this could work: https://www.bike-components.de/en/Procraft/Kettenblatt-9-fach-5-Arm-130mm-Lochkreis-p27814/. 8 and 9 speed chainrings are very close in thickness, I have been using 9-speed TA chainrings in a 8 speed setup for years.